# Using intersphinx with automodule directive

Tags: django, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I use Sphinx to document Django application with intesphinx extension and I was wondering if I could take advantage of existing `intersphinx_mapping` to Django documentation for `automodule` directive.

I can successfully reference Django labels in my reST sources.

For example, I have this directive:

```
.. automodule:: email_app.models.dbmail_models
   :members:
```

As a result I get this excerpt:

> class email_app.models.dbmail_models.**DbmailMessages**(...)
>       Bases: **django.db.models.base.Model**

where `django.db.models.base.Model` is not a link to `` :ref:`django:django.db.models.base.Model `` but a regular string, while I would like to make it a link to `django.db.models.base.Model` label in Django online docs.

Is it possible to accomplish this kind of interaction?

Comment: did you find any solution for this task? I have the same problem